# Is it possible to make two TableLayoutPanels line up?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with multiple tablelayoutpanels on it - I'm using them to make sure that controls line up even if the resolution changes.  The columns are all set to autosize, to ensure that the controls are all visible.

However, there's no way to make the columns autosize between the different panels.  Which means that the different sections of the form don't align with each other.

Is there a standard solution to this that I'm missing?

---

To be clear, what I'm doing is something like this:

```
ControlSet 1
Label 1: Control 1    Label 2: Control 2
Label 3: Control 3    Label 4: Control 4

Controlset 2
Label 5: WiderControl 5 Label 6: Control 6
Label 7: Control 7      Label 8: Control 8
```

What I want is for the two sets of controls to line up with each other, automatically, in all resolutions/font sizes.  Easy to do with one set (tablelayoutpanel is pretty-much designed for this), can't make it work with multiple sets.

Thanks!

Comment: First I have to ask why the two sets, then?  Can it not just be done with careful layout of a single `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: I need to see some screen shot to show what you want, this kind of question is hardly to imagine and needs some screen shot.

Comment: You could make parent-child relation between multiple `TableLayoutPanel`. Parent will have autosizing/autoscaling etc. And childs will be watching for the parent sizes and set them when they are changed (there should be an event, probably with the word `Layout` in it). Or parent can set sizes of childs if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **just one** `TableLayoutPanel` with 4 columns and 6 rows:

`ControlSet 1` is put into (0;0) and have `RowSpan = 4`.

`ControlSet 2` is put into (3;0) and also have `RowSpan = 4`.

How to put rest of controls should be obvious I think.

Comment: Not if I need to put headers and other formatting around each table.  Sorry, but it needs to be multiple tables.

Comment: Yes, you can. Do formatting in the `cells`. You do not need nesting and anything what is "near" to each other can be hold in just one `TableLayoutPanel`. Or describe better your case.